# How to Interact With Moodle REST API

Tags: moodle

so i want to build mobile app with flutter like moodleApp, so that app just fetch api from the existing moodle web,
then, does moodle provid API to be used freely? or any other way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Moodle provide API

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Core_APIs

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client

```
Example : https://example.com/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=...&wsfunction=...&moodlewsrestformat=json
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning, that the moodle webservice is not a typical REST API like designed nowadays. Example: You can get all courses but you neither can filter by several parameters, no you'll get an efficient way of paginating content.

Comment: @Wolf-Tech I think the biggest difference between REST and Moodle-REST is that latter is not based on resources. It's just RPC wrapped in HTTP

Answer (score 0):

To enable **Moodle as an API** (here it calls `Web-Services`) and create endpoint to make **external HTTP-requests** you need to follow these steps:

1. Enable Web-Services support `/admin/settings.php?section=optionalsubsystems#admin-enablewebservices`
2. Enable REST protocol `/admin/settings.php?section=webserviceprotocols`
3. Create your Web-Service `/admin/webservice/service.php?id=0`
4. Create token for your WS `/admin/webservice/tokens.php?action=create`
5. At Services list `/admin/settings.php?section=externalservices` add an external function to your WS (click `Functions` next to your WS). Here you can add [core external functions](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions), also it is possible to [create an own ones with your plugin](https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/subsystems/external/writing-a-service).
6. Read docs [how to create endpoint](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client) with **token**, **function** and **protocol** and pass needle params to it.

### Plugin for Moodle Web-Services

Moodle `API/Web-Service` is a big issue with a lot of things, to control and **easy manage it from one place** there is a local plugin [WSManager](https://github.com/liliapro/moodle-local_wsmanager).